# Why does runtime reduce when we use functions instead of two nested for loops

Tags: time-complexity, function-call

I've observed that runtime of a program which has two nested loops is greater then runtime of same code that uses a function instead of inner loop. Why does that happen when we are performing same logic in both cases.

Here is the sample code to print primes in range using function:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n;
        boolean flag;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        n=input.nextInt();
        long st=System.nanoTime();
        for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
        {

            if(isPrime(i))
            {
                System.out.printf("%d ",i);
            }
        }
        long et = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%.4f",(et-st)/1000000000.0);
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(int n)
    {
        for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The time taken to run this program is 0.017s for input of 1000.
Now if i use a nested for loop in same code instead of function the execution time became nearly 1.26s. 
So my question is why does nesting of loops increase time when we are performing same number of operations in both cases.

Comment: Which language are you talking about?

Comment: Also a code sample would be handy